# data formatting: reformat AND rearrange multiple dataframes in r into single file

Tags: r, list, csv, dataframe, lapply

I have many .csv files that are auto formatted data from another source. The order of that data is terrible for my (anyone's!) analyses. Ideally, I would like combine all of these separate .csv files into a single dataframe, where each row represents the contents of an original dataframe, and the first column in the row has the name of the original dataframe.

I am able to automatically import each original dataframe using a list

```
#import from working directory
temp = list.files(pattern="*.csv")
list2env(
  lapply(setNames(temp, make.names(gsub("*.csv$", "", temp))), 
         read.csv), envir = .GlobalEnv)

#make a new list of dataframes that I should be able to use with "lapply"
files<-eapply(.GlobalEnv,is.data.frame)
```

I would like to reformat each dataframe in the list in the following way:

```
#reproducible example original format
df1<-data.frame(matrix(NA, nrow=3, ncol=3))
colnames(df1)<-c("area", "mean", "sd")
rownames(df1)<-c("A", "B", "C")
df1[1:3,1]<-30
df1[,2]<-sample(80:100, 3, replace=TRUE)
df1[,3]<-sample(1:5, 3, replace=TRUE)
df1

   area mean sd
A   30   81  1
B   30   96  3
C   30   97  4

df2<-data.frame(matrix(NA, nrow=3, ncol=3))
colnames(df2)<-c("area", "mean", "sd")
rownames(df2)<-c("A", "B", "C")
df2[1:3,1]<-35
df2[,2]<-sample(80:100, 3, replace=TRUE)
df2[,3]<-sample(1:5, 3, replace=TRUE)
df2

   area mean sd
A   35   82  2
B   35   99  1
C   35  100  3

#desired final format:
  filename area.1 mean.1a sd.1a mean.1b sd.1b mean.1c sd.1c
1    file1     30      81     1      96     3      97     4
2    file2     35      82     2      99     1     100     3
```

I've been trying to write an ugly loop that basically does this:

```
#desired final format
df1.2<-data.frame(matrix(NA, nrow=2, ncol=8))
colnames(df1.2)<-c("filename", "area.1", "mean.1a", "sd.1a", "mean.1b", "sd.1b", "mean.1c", "sd.1c")
df1.2[1,1]<-"file1"
df1.2[1,2]<-df1[1,1] 
df1.2[1,3]<-df1[1,2] 
df1.2[1,4]<-df1[1,3]
df1.2[1,5]<-df1[2,2] 
df1.2[1,6]<-df1[2,3]
df1.2[1,7]<-df1[3,2]
df1.2[1,8]<-df1[3,3]
```

But I cannot figure out how to manipulate *individual elements* within a dataframe from a list.

I know there has to be an efficient way to do this, but I've never really worked with lists before and I can't figure out how to make it behave the way I want. All the examples I've found seem to be using lapply to do something more basic like average an entire row or change an entire attribute, not copy a single element within a dataframe within a list.

I am not very familiar with lists, and I think that is causing my heartache here. I would love help using lapply and/or a for loop (or some fabulous function that I don't know about) so that I can write one script to iterate through all the dataframes in the list, and either simultaneously include the filename as the first column, or else use "rbind" later to add it in.

Comment: Isn't `subset` manipulation what you are looking for?

Comment: I'm not sure how `subset` would apply here. I've accepted an answer below, thanks for weighing in!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did I understand rightly that your input data is a list of dataframes?

If so, here's a wad of duct tape that should get you there.

```
biglist <- list()
areas <- seq(30,45,by=5)
for(i in 1:4) {
  biglist[[i]]<-data.frame(matrix(NA, nrow=3, ncol=3))
  colnames(biglist[[i]])<-c("area", "mean", "sd")
  rownames(biglist[[i]])<-c("A", "B", "C")
  biglist[[i]][1:3,1]<-areas[i]
  biglist[[i]][,2]<-sample(80:100, 3, replace=TRUE)
  biglist[[i]][,3]<-sample(1:5, 3, replace=TRUE)
}
biglist
## [[1]]
##   area mean sd
## A   30  100  3
## B   30   86  1
## C   30   85  1
## 
## [[2]]
##   area mean sd
## A   35   83  4
## B   35   87  2
## C   35   88  4
## 
## [[3]]
##   area mean sd
## A   40   92  4
## B   40   80  3
## C   40   90  5
## 
## [[4]]
##   area mean sd
## A   45   97  2
## B   45   92  3
## C   45   92  5
```

Now the fun part...

```
df1.2<-data.frame(matrix(NA, nrow=length(biglist), ncol=8))
colnames(df1.2)<-c("filename", "area.1", "mean.1a", "sd.1a", "mean.1b", "sd.1b", "mean.1c", "sd.1c")

for(i in 1:length(biglist)) {
  df1.2[i,2:8] <- c(biglist[[i]][1,], biglist[[i]][2,2:3], biglist[[i]][3,2:3])
}
df1.2$filename <- paste0("file",1:length(biglist))

df1.2
##   filename area.1 mean.1a sd.1a mean.1b sd.1b mean.1c sd.1c
## 1    file1     30     100     3      86     1      85     1
## 2    file2     35      83     4      87     2      88     4
## 3    file3     40      92     4      80     3      90     5
## 4    file4     45      97     2      92     3      92     5
```

Not the most elegant, but does this get what you need?

Comment: Thanks, Matt, this "wad of duct tape" was exactly what I needed! Turns out part of my issue was that the way I had generated my list it didn't actually contain the dataframes.... but I don't think I would have figured that out without your answer, and I certainly wouldn't have come up with this on my own. Many, many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If each data frame has the same number of rows, you can flatten them with `unlist` and then bind them in a common data frame. For example:

```
df1 <- unlist(df1)
df2 <- unlist(df2)

df <- data.frame()
df <- rbind(df, c("file1", df1), stringsAsFactors = F)
df <- rbind(df, c("file2", df2), stringsAsFactors = F)

colnames(df) <- c("filname", names(df1))

df <- df[,-c(3:4)]
```

Output:

```
  filname area1 mean1 mean2 mean3 sd1 sd2 sd3
1   file1    30    94    96    99   2   2   3
2   file2    35    92    95    90   2   3   5
```

Comment: Thanks @ssp3nc3r. I had considered flattening them into a single dataframe as you suggest, and rearranging from there, but I have >200 of these to concatenate, and I was worried I would lose track of something if I did that.